# Document management tool recommendations for PowerPoint and Markdown

Tags: open-source, document-management, latex, powerpoint

I know there must be something out there that does what I am looking for, but I am hoping someone here may already be familiar with it or know of something similar.

I have a library of modules that are PowerPoint slides. Each module consists of 2-3 slides to 15-20 slides. They each cover a skill that can be combined with other modules to create a class, i.e. an instructional training class. Classes are composed of multiple modules but are grouped into various headings.

For example, a class might have four (4) major subjects: Security, Networking, Operating Systems, and Programming. In each of these subjects there might be 5-10 different modules; e.g. Operating Systems might have four (4) modules covering MS Windows, MacOS, Linux (various flavors), and UNIX. Each module may have 10-15 or even 20+ slides.

I use Pandoc to combine these modules into a larger slide deck. I do the same with the workbook exercises and use Markdown to turn the various exercise modules into a larger PDF document.

So... here's my question:

Is there some sort of management tool that would allow me to click and drag the slides, documents, and text files into a larger workflow area, and then click "Build", which would then generate a final .pptx or .pdf file?

I guess there might be some sort of LMS out there that handles this, but it would be nice to be able to move files around in a graphical workflow and customize a class to suit an individual customer.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance.